# WPF flat carousel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What is the best way to do an animated flat (2D) carousel in WPF 3.5 ?

I need to display horizontally, a dynamic list of items in 2 rows and 3 columns. I need previous & next buttons to scroll columns by columns.

I have tried a wrappanel in a listbox, but how to scroll item by item (with repeat buttons) ?

Answer (score -1):

Well you could increment/decrement the `SelectedIndex` property on your `ItemsControl`. Or get a [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) from your `ItemsSource` and use for example [MoveCurrentToNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrenttonext.aspx), if you have [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) set to true.